# Build failed after updating Xcode from 10.3 to 11.0 (react-native)

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, xcode11

I cannot build iOS locally (on simulator) after updating my Xcode from 10.3 to 11.0.

When I build my iOS app on BuddyBuild with Xcode version 11.0 everything is working - build successful.

But I cannot build my app in simulator.

- When I run command `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8"` I got this error:

> error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it
>   exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider
>   building your app with Xcode.app, by opening myApp.xcworkspace

- When I run my app from **myApp.xcworkspace** I got this error:

> ld: library not found for -lBVLinearGradient clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How I can fix this?

Very strange is that **build is working when I am building my app on BuddyBuild** service. 
But I cannot build and test my app in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This was a issue with `react-native-linear-gradient` library.
I changed version to 2.4.0 and everything is working fine now. Strange.